# How to check if a broadcast has been received or not?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a `broadcast` to a `Fragment` from `FirebaseMessagingService` class, Is there any way of knowing that the broadcast has been received by the fragment other than having a variable which stores whether this fragment has been initialised or not and then send the broadcast(`But it will only work if Fragment does get killed between sending the broadcast`)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this easily by ResultReceiver:

1. Make your custom ResultReceiver.
2. So now, you can pass object of ResultReceiver (which is Parcebale) from `FirebaseMessagingService` to your Activity, so on client-side (in Activity) you will get ResultReceiver and invoke method send(...) when user's UI updated.
3. Handle result from Activity in ResultReceiver.

You can also make some improvements if user's UI updated but he left from activity in that moment (imagine chat app, where user still in app, and in this moment when push comes to device, UI changed, but he can't see properly that updateting cuz he left from activity in that second). In this situation you can get UI Handler of activity and make a message which you will enqueue with postDelayed (1-2 seconds) to this Handler. So now in handleMessage() you will invoke send(...) of ResultReceiver.